# I am looking for a list of the possible error that could occur during processing

Tags: php, balanced-payments

Can you tell me where your list of errors which was at https://github.com/balanced/balanced-api/blob/master/errors.rst has gone?
It is useful for writing exception handling, even just to know the possible errors for which one should check.

Comment: Why in the world would Stack Overflow have a list of errors hosted on Github regarding balancedpayments? That doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Perhaps you could have just asked before down voting.  This is tagged balanced-payments because that is the stackoverflow tag for them.  It is here because balanced give this as a resource for questions and there was no answer on chat.  The question clearly asks where a pre-existing list has been moved to, it does not expect to find on on stackoverflow.

Comment: "Can you tell me where YOUR list of errors have gone" implies that StackOverflow maintains a list of them, on Github, on behalf of balancedpayments and that you expect Stackoverflow to have anything to do with maintaining said list. Balanced may direct you here for things such as working with the API, and that is why the tag exists and what it is for. Regardless, you need to be contacting Balanced Payments as they are the only entity which can actually provide you with an answer. Also, don't presume that just because this was a ridiculous place to ask said question that I even downvoted you.

Comment: Already contacted balanced and probably due to time zone did not get reply, however they are very good at answering questions posted here.  The question is clearly aimed at the people who maintain the list, hence the words "your list" and the link to the previous location. Stackoverflow covers lots of areas, hence the clever tag system. As you say "Balanced may direct you here for things such as working with the API", that is what I need the error list for.  If you chose to infer incorrectly that is really your problem.  If you can't help why comment except to be destructive?

Comment: I'm not being destructive at all - I just don't get how you don't see trying to poll SO on something they have no control over is the quickest way to get an answer - I'm trying to help you save time.

Comment: You don't know the answer but your insistence on commenting wastes my time when I get notified there has been a comment here and check it in case it is useful.  Balanced are part of the SO community as are other people who have implemented balanced and they use this tag to communicate.  If your intentions were genuinely benevolent then thank you, as you can see I have already thought of contacting balanced directly as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to have been moved here: https://github.com/balanced/balanced-api/blob/revision0/errors.rst

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer links to the errors specification for Balanced API v1.0, https://github.com/balanced/balanced-api/blob/revision0/errors.rst.

For those looking for the error specification for Balanced API v1.1, visit https://github.com/balanced/balanced-api/blob/master/fixtures/_models/error.json.